# What is the preferred way of preparing data in automatic testing

Tags: testing, tdd

Lets say I want to test a method of a class representing a user account. I have a fixture which contains several user records from which I want to choose one. What is the preferred method here?

1. Pick user record by unique ID ("pick user with ID=X")
2. Pick user record by some readable date like name or email address ("pick user with email='name@example.com'").
3. Pick user record by properties that are related to the test I make, e.g. if I want to test if a user with the role "admin" can access a specific method, I could pick the first admin user I can find ("pick user with role='admin'").

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing *unittesting*, you declare the objects you test on in your fixture. There is no 'loading' involved whatsoever. You simply create an instance of an object if you need it, set the fields so that the state of the object matches the state needed in your test and use the variable you assigned it to in your test.

```
[Test]
public void AdminUserShouldHaveBackUpAccess()
{
    var user = new User { IsAdmin = true };
    Assert.That(user.CanAccess("backup"), Is.True);
}

[Test]
public void RegularUserShouldNotHaveBackUpAccess()
{
    var user = new User { IsAdmin = false };
    Assert.That(user.CanAccess("backup"), Is.False);
}
```

Comment: You are right, what I want to do is not unittesting because there are related components involved that I do not want to prepare for every test. So I prepared some fixture data that I can use for different test situation - but in each test situation I want to pick a different user.

Comment: In that case, create a class like 'TestFixtureDataProvider' with methods like 'GetAdminUser' or 'GetRegularUser' or 'GetUserWithLockedAccount' and so on... Make methods that create your test data and give them explicit names.